# Reading HTML table data / html tag

Tags: asp.net, html, stream, streamreader

I have some 50 pages of html which have around 100-plus rows of data in each, with all sort of CSS style, I want to read the html file and just get the data, like Name, Age, Class, Teacher. and store it in Database, but I am not able to read the html tags

e.g 
space i kept to display it here

```
<table class="table_100">
    <tr>
        <td class="col_1">
            <span class="txt_student">Gauri Singh</span><br>
            <span class="txt_bold">13</span><br>
            <span class="txt_bold">VIII</span><br>
        </td>
        <td class="col_2">
            <span class="txt_teacher">Praveen M</span><br>
            <span class="txt_bold">3494</span><br>
            <span class="txt_bold">3Star</span><br>
        </td>
        <td class="col_3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems like a good example of how not to use data tables, if what you're trying to do is get at the things in spans. A nested table would have given you much more immediately meaningful markup.

Comment: also can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397659/create-a-dictionary-or-list-from-stringhtml-tag-included-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET you may try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
You could "convert" HTML pages to XML documents with this:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"..\..\your_page.htm");
        doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
        doc.Save("your_page.xml");
```

And then just parse a XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It provides an intuitive and robust .net API for parsing and otherwise toying with Html.